# Tensorflow: Loss function for Binary classification (without one hot labels)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to use binary cross entropy for binary classification problem and keep running into following error, I have tried type casting as well as reshaping the tensor to shape [-1, 1], but nothing seems to work out.

My Last 2 Layers are defined as,

`dense_fin2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = dense_fin, units = 128, name = "dense_fin2")
 logits = tf.sigmoid(tf.layers.dense(inputs = dense_fin2, units = 1, name = "logits"))`

Loss function,

```
loss = labels * -tf.log(logits) + (1 - labels) * -tf.log(1 - logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

Error thrown by tensorflow,

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("Neg:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)'
```

Extra information,
I am using Estimator API coupled with Dataset API. I have integer labels i.e. 0 or 1. They are **NOT** one-hot encoded. I understand this is doable by one hot encoding my labels but I do not want to take that path.

Answer (score 1):

This error likely comes from trying to multiply integer-type labels with float-type logits. You can explicity cast the labels to float via `tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.float32)`. Unfortunately your question does not reveal whether you tried this specific casting.

However, for reasons of numerical stability I would advise you to use `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead (or `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy`). This is also a good idea for *correctness*; cross-entropy uses log-probabilities, but you are already putting in logits (which are log unnormalized probabilities) so the extra `tf.log` is actually wrong. You could also add a `tf.nn.sigmoid` activation to the output layer to make it correct, however the built-in functions are still preferrable for stability.

Comment: I have casted the labels and it seems to go through but using,
`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` produces this error, 
 `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 8 values, but the requested shape has 1`, on the other hand using the loss function which I have stated above produces NaN error. So your point about numeric stability seems valid.